# How to turn off proxy with java package manager?

Tags: java, proxy, liferay, package-managers

In this link I am using blade cli for liferay and turning on the proxy settings:

https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/setting-blade-cli-proxy-requirments

> jpm command --jvmargs "-Dhttp(s).proxyHost=[your proxy host]
>   -Dhttp(s).proxyPort=[your proxy port]" jpm

I googled but could not find how to turn the proxy settings off with jpm?

Comment: By omitting the -D options. You can omit the `--jvmargs` as well.

Comment: Tried that. What is the exact input?